# What's the scalajs equivalent of per page javascript?

Tags: scala, playframework, scala.js

Suppose I already have an play app, with three or four pages, each one of which has a seperate javascript script file imported at the bottom.

eg

```
   <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/detailsPage.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Each one contains some specific behaviour - jquery events, or an EventSource listener for that page, which isn't necessary on other pages. (The EventSource isn't on every page).

Going forward, I'd like to give scalajs a try. But that produces a single script file, which expects to be included in all pages. I'm not worried about the overhead - the javascript file will be cached.

But what's the equivalent way of structuring my scalajs so that I can include the appropriate behaviour in each page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the canonical answer is here, but have ended up doing the following:

Each "script" is declared in an object with a single `@JSExportTopLevel` (needs scalajs 0.6.15 or above) function:

```
@JSExportTopLevel("enhancedFrobnication")
def main(): Unit = {
}
```

The full scalajs file is then included in the main method, and specific bits of functionality are switched on in short `<script>` sections after that has been included:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">enhancedFrobnication();</script>
```